# I use PHP CAS but when I want to logout, it failes because of an infinite redirection loop

Tags: php, cas

I use PHP CAS but when I want to logout, it failes because of an infinite redirection loop
    include_once('CAS.php');

```
include_once('dbconnect.php');

phpCAS::client(CAS_VERSION_2_0,'login.mydomain.com',443,'', false);
phpCAS::setDebug('/tmp/phpCAS.log');


phpCAS::setNoCasServerValidation();
phpCAS::forceAuthentication();


if(isset($_REQUEST['logout'])) 
{

    if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
        if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
            session_start();
        }
    }
    session_destroy() ;
    phpCAS::logout();
}  

$casUser = phpCAS::getUser();
```

Comment: Please add the description about what is going wrong with this code.

Comment: Can you start session in this way? It should be at the beginning of the file - the very first line. Disclaimer - I didn't use CAS.

Comment: Actually After I get $casUser, I start session in my code. I'm pretty sure that there is something with CAS. But I don't know what it is..if($casUser) 
{
 session_start() ;
  $_SESSION['user_id']   = $casUser ; }